# Library error while Installing .Net Core

Tags: libraries, microsoft

I have a sniffer to create in Visual Basic, yet I (obviously) use Ubuntu. Therefore I tried to download **.Net Core** as far as it is now available along with Mono. But I am unable to download it properly. Indeed, after having followed [this tutorial from microsoft.com](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#ubuntu), I have the following output for `:~$ dotnet new` command:

```
$ dotnet new
A fatal error occurred, the required library libhostfxr.so could not be found
```

Therefore, I don't know if I am able to devlop in Visual Basic yet. And I found almost no informations on this library on the internet.

**How can deal with this problem and desing my VB sniffer?**

Furthermore, I actually don't understand at all how does Visual Studio Code works but I downloaded it. Then they recommended to install the C# extension. I don't know if it would allow me wright in Visual Basic but, still, I wasn't able to connect and have the following error:

```
connect EHOSTUNREACH 192.168.1.254:3128
```

Comment: Which "tutorial from microsoft.com" did you follow? Can you provide a link or summarize the link and add your summary  to the question? Also, by "Visual Studio Code", are you referring to the Visual Studio Code editor (https://code.visualstudio.com/)?

Comment: @edwinksl Sorry! Iupdated and yes, this is definitely the product I was aiming at.

Comment: I am not sure if this would help: https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/3657#issuecomment-227610791. Worst comes to worst, you can just uninstall everything.

Comment: @edwinksl God. Okay, how should I uninstall?

Comment: Hmm, I don't think you need to. After reading the GitHub issue I linked, this is what I suggest (no safety guaranteed though!):  1) From Step 2 of the tutorial you linked, there is a link to a script that removes all previous versions of .NET Core. Run that script. 2) Run `sudo apt-get install dotnet-dev-1.0.0-preview2-003118`.

Comment: @edwinksl Great! It works for .Net. Yet, do you have an idea for Visual Studio Code C#? Wouldn'it it be easier to code with thier graphical interface?

Comment: You can use any editor you want to code in C# though. I see no need to use Visual Studio Code unless you want to learn a new editor.

Comment: @edwinksl Actually I have to learn how to code in the real Visual Studio, is it an alternative?

Comment: Yeah, probably.

Comment: Your current question consists of 2 separate parts, so I suggest spinning out your question about the C# extension into a new separate question that hopefully someone else can answer. I will write an answer to respond to the .NET Core part.

Answer (score 7):

Using the discussion at https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/3657, I would suggest the following to install a newer version of .NET Core that fixes the problem:

1. From Step 2 of the tutorial you linked, there is a link to a script that removes all previous versions of .NET Core. Run that script.
2. Run `sudo apt-get install dotnet-dev-1.0.0-preview2-003118`.